# CSS Menus - loosing hover effect (corrected link)

Tags: css

On the following site:

http://steve.brettatkin.com/Templates/3-column.php

What needs to change with the CSS to not loose the hover green text color of the main navigation when moving over to the secondary links?

Here is the CSS file:

http://steve.brettatkin.com/inc/css/3-col.css

Thanks

Brett

Comment: You added a link to localhost.  Nobody is going to be able to view your page.

Comment: im sorry friend but you post a local link... no one will be able to see that.

Comment: crap, sorry.  I've updated the URL's

Answer (score 0):

add a class "whatever" to your li, then add this to your css:

> ```
> .whatever:hover > a {
>     color:#8EC23F !important;
> }
> ```

You'll also need to set the doctype to

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> ```

for FF

Comment: That did it, thanks.  HTML 4.01?  What version of FF and what OS?

Comment: FF5 Win7. I don't fully know about doctype, but the last time I needed to use that for FF to recognize hover on elements other than <a>. I'm pretty sloppy with doctype, so.. whatever works :))

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to specify :hover pseudo class to every child a tag of ul li and sub ul li.. just add a:hover inside  main ul li and the further child elements of ul li ul li a or maybe deep enough ul li ul li ul li a will get the same property from the its parents (incase you didn't alter or add some extra css at the grand child level )..